# Angular - Form control invalid error not showing if set the value to form control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups, angular-validation

I have this editor

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

setting its value to form control.

```
this.FrmGroup.get("name").setValue(this.quill.root.innerHTML)`
```

```
<div *ngIf="FrmGroup.get('name').invalid && (FrmGroup.get('name').dirty || FrmGroup.get('name').touched)">
  <small class="validation-error">Please provide a name.</small>
</div>
```

The value is empty but the error is not shown.

Form group Structure:

```
this.FrmGroup = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  Description: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: Can you show how the `FrmGroup` structure look like? Did you implement `Validators.required` to the `name` form control? And are you trying to check the HTML in the `editor` div element right?

Comment: @YongShun yes i have added in my code above can you pls check, for name only where editor is there it is not showing error message but it is validating

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here:

```
*ngIf="FrmGroup.get('name').invalid && (FrmGroup.get('name').dirty || FrmGroup.get('name').touched)"
```

which the HTML element is rendered only by fulfilling:

1. The form control is invalid
2. At the same time the form control is either dirty or touched.

---

Either:

You should mask the form control dirty or touched after setting the value.

```
this.FrmGroup.get('name')!.setValue(this.quill?.root.innerHTML);
this.FrmGroup.get('name')!.markAsDirty();
// Or
this.FrmGroup.get('name')!.markAsTouched();
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hhcqdl?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Or remove the logic for checking the form control is dirty or touched if it is not required.

```
*ngIf="FrmGroup.get('name').invalid"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use control status css classes, like in documentation https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes